# SQLite - Limit vfs file count

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a directory structure of individual databases (around 500) that are accessed via individual connections. Processing queries can be quite slow however. Profiling has given me the hint that the reason is that every connection ( set up via sqlite3_open_v2 ) uses the default vfs which, after enough connections, has 500 entries and every sqlite function that searches through this list takes some time.

Now my question:
Would it be possible to speed up the process by creating an individual vfs for each connection since I never access more than one table from a connection? If yes, how can this be achieved?

Regards

Comment: Where exactly does the profiler point to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also contacted SQLite support. The problem is known and a fix will go into a future release. Thanks anyways!